# Interpretation of 「ミスターハスラー楽屋から火だすな」 in a song

Tags: translation, song-lyrics, jargon

I'm trying to understand the lyrics of the song [刹那 by Creepy Nuts](https://youtu.be/IXoFWdAiq2g) (link to Youtube video with lyrics).

I'm in the woods and the most enigmatic is this passage [here](https://youtu.be/IXoFWdAiq2g?t=138). The lyrics go:

> シラフじゃいられない まぁわかるが
>   **ミスターハスラー楽屋から火だすな**
>   キャリア、立場、時代かしがらみか？
>   ちょうど良い言い訳は見つかりました？

Starting with the meaning of ハスラー I found only [this answer](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1041780120) suggesting it is 薬取り扱う人, which I guess from the context must be *drug user*.

> シラフじゃいられない まぁわかるが
>   ミスターハスラー楽屋から火だすな

My pure guess would be:

> I can't stand being sober, but I guess I need to hide it (like a weed smoking-artist does not let the smoke out of the backstage)

Then for:

> キャリア、立場、時代かしがらみか？
>   ちょうど良い言い訳は見つかりました？

I suppose:

> Is it career, position, the times, or it's connections
>   That would be a good excuse (for not getting the job).

But my question is mostly about ミスターハスラー楽屋から火だすな (I'm not sure how it connects to the latter part).

Answer (score 2):

I think this song saying about the mental state of a rapper challenging [free style](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB_(%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%83%97)) rap competition.

So based on this, シラフ seems saying rather "sane", "normal", "calm," etc. than being "sober".

> **ミスターハスラー**楽屋から火だすな

ミスター probably means self proclamation to represent something.

ハスラー probably means a drug dealer as you said and a rapper from their own indie label founded by the profit.

[楽屋から火だす](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%A5%BD%E5%B1%8B%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E7%81%AB%E3%82%92%E5%87%BA%E3%81%99-460806), which literally means "put on fire in the backstage", it is an idiomatic expression; self-destructive, self-ruinous, shoot yourself in the foot, etc.

So, I guess it's saying "self-proclaimed renowned [hip-hop hustler](https://www.ft.com/content/63b84464-9d41-11e2-a8db-00144feabdc0), don't shoot yourself in the foot."

> キャリア、立場、時代かしがらみか？ちょうど良い言い訳は見つかりました？

I am not so sure the context of rap scene that much, but I guess this line says;

"Career, Status, Times, Constraints? Do you find any good excuse? (you can't perform well in the battle for not being able to win)"

> *But my question is mostly about* ミスターハスラー楽屋から火だすな *(I'm not sure how it connects to the latter part).*

All in all, I guess the latter part is saying *"stop bluffing or deceit and prove yourself"*.